# How to attach Click event with a button on popup fancybox>

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am not being able to attach Click Event with a Popup form that contains an `input` button. Code is given below:

```
<a id="btnEditSummary" href=#>Edit Summary </a>
<div id="editSummary" class="hidden">
     <input type=button id="btnEdit" value="Update" />
    </div>

function openPoPup(clickHandle,contentHandle,width,height)
{
    width = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 600;
    height = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 300;

    $.fancybox(
        $(contentHandle).html(),
        {
            'width'             : width,
            'height'            : height,
            'minWidth'          :  width,
            'minHeight'         :  height,
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'onStart': function () {
                //On Start callback if needed
            }
        }
    );
}    
$("#btnEditSummary").click(function()
            {
                openPoPup('#btnEditSummary','#editSummary',300,300);

                $( "#btnEdit" ).on( "click", function() {
                    alert( $( this ).text() );
                });

            }
    $( "#btnEdit" ).on( "click", function() {
                    alert( $( this ).text() );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your method is that you are actually displaying in fancybox a `clone` of your `#editSummary` *selector*, passed as parameter within the `openPoPup()` function so the `click` event is bound to the original *selector* in your document flow but not to the `clone` inside fancybox.

As a workaround, you could use the fancybox `onComplete` callback (I am assuming you are using v1.3.4 because the API options in your code) to bind the `click` event to the element `#btnEdit` inside fancybox like :

```
function openPoPup(clickHandle, contentHandle, width, height) {
    width = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 600;
    height = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 300;

    $.fancybox($(contentHandle).html(), {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        // minWidth: width, // not valid in v1.3.x but 2.x
        // minHeight: height, // not valid in v1.3.x but 2.x
        autoScale: true,
        transitionIn: 'none',
        transitionOut: 'none',
        hideOnContentClick: false,
        onStart: function () {
            //On Start callback if needed
        },
        onComplete: function () {
            // bind click event to element inside fancybox
            $("#fancybox-content").on("click", "#btnEdit", function () {
                alert("click event bound");
            });
        }
    });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#btnEditSummary").click(function () {
        openPoPup('#btnEditSummary', '#editSummary', 300, 300);
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** I am using `.on()` in its delegated form :

```
$("#fancybox-content").on("click", "#btnEdit", function (){ ... });
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/174pwpqs/)**

Comment: @Volatil3 then use the proper API options and callbacks:  `afterShow` instead of `onComplete` for instance and `.fancybox-inner` instead of `#fancybox-content`